# Run Windows 10 File Explorer as Admin

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

On my own home machine, Windows 10 Pro, I have a folder off the C: root named "local". I put utility programs in there and put the folder on the path.

I finished writing a utility today and attempted to copy/paste it into the \local\ folder (using File Explorer) and got the message that I would need to provide Administrator privilege. I clicked the button with the admin 'shield' icon in that dialog, thinking it might elevate my privilege for this operation, but it failed.

So I went looking for a way to run File Explorer with admin privilege. I would rather not download a new utility program or extra shell, I do not want to edit the registry, and I do not want to put a shortcut on my desktop -- I am hoping that there is SOME way, as an admin on the machine, to run this basic utility with admin privilege when I actually need to.

I found a page that indicated I could find the exe file in \Windows\, right-click it and choose "Run as Administrator"; I found the file and did that, but got the same message when I attempted to copy the file into my \local\ folder.

Is there a way to do this? I must have been able to copy EXE files into the folder before, and don't remember having this much trouble over it.

EDIT: I found the Explorer.exe file in the C:\WINDOWS\ folder, right-clicked and selected "Run as Adminstrator", got the warning dialog about making changes to my system, and attempted the copy/paste there. It still tells me I need to provide admin privilege.

EDIT: screenshot of security settings on the folder as requested:

[image: Security Settings]

FURTHER EDIT: invocation and output of Dism RestoreHealth:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.18362.1

Image Version: 10.0.18362.592

[==========================100.0%==========================] The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.
```

EDIT: RESPONSE TO SUGGESTION OF SIMILARITY TO ANOTHER QUESTION:

Unfortunately the suggested question is not close to my own; I'm not trying to run it as a different user. I want to run it so I can copy files from one folder I created to another folder I created.

EDIT: FURTHER INFORMATION

The problem seems dependent on the extension of the file I'm attempting to copy -- if I use a CMD prompt that I run as admin, and attempt to copy the file, I get the error 'access denied'. If I rename that file to be a .txt file, it copies without problem. If I then try to rename that file to be .exe, I get 'access denied'. So I conclude that the thing I'm prevented from doing is putting an EXE file into this directory that I created. An odd thing about that is that I put a different EXE file in that directory yesterday morning, according to its timestamp.

Comment: It is not possible to run File Explorer as an Administrator.  While you might have permission issues, the solution, isn't to run File Explorer as an Administrator.  Please provide the ACL on the folder in question.

Comment: @rcook - I apologize for not being clear.  I wanted a screenshot.  You still need to run the [DISM](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and SFC commands, and indicate if those commands suggest any system corruption.  We cannot help you without this information.  Likewise, all relevant information must be in the question body, comments are temporary.

Comment: @rcook - I provided you support documentation on DISM.

Comment: I have had this happen. The next repair step past DISM is Repair Install. Do that. It will take an hour or two; otherwise after answering prompts, it is just watching paint dry

Comment: @John ok, DISM run as indicated in a question edit. It only took a few minutes. No problems indicated.

Comment: @music2myear Unfortunately not, I'm not trying to run it as a different user. I want to run it so I can copy files from one folder I created to another folder I created.